# Image Paths in Processing Java

Tags: java, path, processing

I'm just curious when loading an image into [Processing](https://processing.org/) (Through Java) can I use a path name for an image? I plan to seperate my code and images into seperate folders and I was wondering if I could specify that. See code below:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PImage;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;

public class MusicVisual extends PApplet
{   
    Minim minim;
    AudioPlayer Music;
    AudioMetaData meta;
    BeatDetect beat;
    int r = 200;
    float rad = 70;
    PImage IMG;

    public void settings()
    {
        size(1280, 960);
        IMG = loadImage("Image.png");
    }
```

So instead of the line `IMG = loadImage("Image.png");` could I perhaps say `IMG = loadImage("../Data/Images/Image.png");`

The only reason is because I want this to be a background for an audio visualizaer.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as you use an absolute path. From [loadImage() documentation](https://processing.org/reference/loadImage_.html):

*The file maybe be loaded from anywhere on the local computer using an absolute path (something that starts with / on Unix and Linux, or a drive letter on Windows)*